# How to make InkWell `onLongPress()` override tap on a TextField inside of it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextField` inside of an `InkWell` with an `onLongPress()` callback. The problem is, despite the fact that even when long pressing on the `TextField`, I see the ripple effect on `InkWell`, but the `onLongPress()` does not run after the long press time passes. It only gets me into editing Text. When pressing on the bottom side of the `Card`, everything runs fine.

**In short:** On tap I want to get into `TextField` editing. On long press I want to trigger the `onLongPress()`, not the `TextField`, even if I am pressing on it.

How do I do this? Thank you.

```
InkWell(
  onLongPress: () {
    // do stuff
  }
  child: ListTile(
    title: TextField(),
  ),
),
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: question is bit confusing, the wording

Comment: @TirthPatel I am implementing a multiselect list. So a user can longpress the `Inkwell` and it will be selected. But now when the user longpresses the area of a `TextField` in a `Inkwell`, it focuses the `TextField` and not fires `onLongPress` of an `Inkwell`. I want to fire the callback on ANY longpress of a `Inkwell`, in any area.

Comment: could you add an example on dartpad?

Comment: @TirthPatel I added basicaly the same setup on dartpad - https://dartpad.dev/7125844edd33f665432fb8b414d32efd . For some reason, if I longpress the `TextField` in dartpad - the `print()` in `onLongPress` of an `Inkwell` fires. In my project basically the same code with the same flutter version igores the `onLongPress` when holding on `TextField`

Comment: maybe that is because dartpad works with browser compilation and I am using flutter on android?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) widget to ignore the `TextField` gesture recognizer:

```
InkWell(
    onLongPress: () {
      print('onLongPress');
    },
    child: AbsorbPointer(
      child: ListTile(
        title: TextField(),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

To still enabling the editing of `TextField` when single tapping on it, you can use `FocusNode` like this:

```
InkWell(
                onLongPress: () {
                  print('onLongPress');
                },
                onTap: () => node.requestFocus(),
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: TextField(
                      focusNode: node,
                      controller: textController,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: You answer pushed me to the right direction, but I needed to edit it a bit. Posted it as another answer to my question. Thank you for help! :)

Comment: just encountered another problem, added the UPD to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Bach 's answer helped me to find a solution. Thank you!

```
InkWell(
  onLongPress: () {
    // do stuff
  },
  child: ListTile(
  title: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode),
    child: AbsorbPointer(
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The only problem is now that I started messing with `focusNode`, multiple input fiels are focusing at the same time. But that is a whole other story ;)

UPD: Just realised, that I can't move text cursor this way. So not useful.

Comment: Each of your text field should use different focus nodes. I'm not clear yet what you mean by cannot move text cursor tho

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `IntrinsicWidth` widget can find the right balance between long press and text editing.

The rationale behind is that `IntrinsicWidth` will let the `TextField` shrink to its minimum width, therefore avoiding a gesture collision with the `InkWell`

So your solution can be like this:

```dart
InkWell(
  onLongPress: () {
    // do stuff
  }
  child: ListTile(
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
      title: TextField(
        //remember to make some hints here
        //because with intrinsicwidth if your textfield is empty it might disappear
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```